# esprima error while trying to use the Browserify module

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, npm, browserify

Alright so I've looked around and cant find anything about this error online.

I'm trying to run Browserify with:

browserify application/main.coffee -w -o public/client_bundle.js

It is producing the error message:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3859 throw e; ^ Error: Line 4: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1161:21) at advance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1089:9) at lookahead (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1118:18) at match (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1239:21) at parseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1638:16) at parsePostfixExpression (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1695:20) at parseUnaryExpression (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1730:20) at parseMultiplicativeExpression (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1781:20) at parseAdditiveExpression (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1798:20) at parseShiftExpression (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/detective/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1815:20)

I have no idea whats happening. I think it might be related to having messed up/incompatible node modules. I have completely removed node/npm and all the node_modules and re-install them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run with `coffeescript`, you need to add more options:

```
$ browserify -c 'coffee -sc' main.coffee > bundle.js
```

Or better still, use the coffeeify module:

```
$ npm install coffeeify
$ browserify -t coffeeify main.coffee > bundle.js
```

Comment: Getting the error with: browserify -t coffeeify main.coffee > bundle.js

Comment: When I try:    browserify -c 'coffee -sc' application/main.coffee > bundle.js     I get an error:       

stream.js:81
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: module not found: "./utilities/util" from file /Users/EventMobi/Documents/Projects/Tile_titans_node/application/main.coffee     Although the file is there and it was working with just plain browserify before

Comment: Is this error coming from browserify, or coffe?  If this module is not needed, perhaps adding `-i ./utilities/util` would help (or some variation of the path.

Comment: Ok so its working now. It turns out that when running `browserify -c 'coffee -sc'` the require statements need the filetype so `require('./utilities/util')` should be `require('./utilities/util.coffee')`. This is odd because previously I would just run browserify without the coffee flag and it would know to compile .coffee to .js.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue but I'm not using any CoffeeScript (unless my inter-dependencies are).